# Homeomorphic Metric Spaces With Non-homeomorphic Completions

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I'm trying to show that homeomorphic metric spaces need not have homeomorphic completions.

My idea was to find two homeomorphic metric spaces with one totally bounded and the other not. Then the completion of the totally bounded metric will be compact, and the other completion will not be compact.

I'm having trouble coming up with specific examples.

Comment: How about $\mathbb R$ and $(0,1)$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks. I didn't think to start with a complete metric to begin with.

Comment: @Newman in any case, you can take $(0,+\infty)$ and $(0,1)$, both non-complete with non-homeomorphic completions: one is compact, the other is not.

Comment: How about the set of all rational numbers, the set of all rational numbers in $[0,1]$, the set of all rational points in $\mathbb R^2$, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarising the comments, plus some more:

$X=\Bbb R$ has itself as its completion, while $Y=(0,1)\simeq X$ has $[0,1]$ as its completion. $\overline{Y}$ is compact while $X$ is not.

$X=(0,+\infty)$ has $\overline{X}=[0,+\infty)$ as its completion, non-compact; while $[0,1)= Y \simeq X$ has $[0,1]$ as its completion, compact.

$X=\Bbb Q$ has $\Bbb R$ as its completion, while $Y$: all end-points of the standard middle third Cantor set $0,1,\frac13,\frac23,\ldots$ are homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ (standard theorem) and $Y$'s completion is the Cantor set. (Very disconnected, as opposed to the reals).

As a generalisation of the last example: let $X'$ and $Y'$ be non-homeomorphic complete separable metric spaces (aka Polish spaces) both without isolated points and $X$ and $Y$ be countable dense subsets of $X'$ resp. $Y'$. Then as countable metric spaces without isolated points $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic and being dense in a Polish space the surrounding space $X'$ resp. $Y'$ is the resp. completion, and are non-homeomorphic. We can take $X'=\Bbb R^n$ for different $n$ e.g.